# Splitting data field String value in Oracle SQl

Tags: sql, string, oracle, split, newline

I have a String Field value in Oracle SQL table. Is there any query so that I can split the string into new lines with certain number of equal characters in each line and the excess characters at the bottom?

```
eg- ABCDEFGHIJ
```

I want to have lines with equal number of characters 4 in each line as follows

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJ
```

The remainder of 2 letters should be at the bottom. Is it possible to achieve this using an Oracle sql query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like the one below using CONNECT BY and LEVEL based on the length of the string.

```sql
WITH d AS (SELECT 'ABCDEFGHIJ' AS str FROM DUAL)
    SELECT SUBSTR (str, ((LEVEL - 1) * 4) + 1, 4)     AS four_letters
      FROM d
CONNECT BY LEVEL < (LENGTH (str) / 4) + 1;
```

Comment: This would work for single row inputs but when you have multiple row inputs it will go wrong as the hierarchical query has no way to correlate one level of the hierarchy to the previous level of the hierarchy so it will correlate each new level with all rows at the previous level and produce exponentially increasing numbers of duplicate rows at each level of the hierarchy. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d60f8d44aedb6c3b1f1192f69d96a7dd)

Comment: @EJ Egyed This is a single row input. How can I modify this function to split lines with 36  or 72 characters?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple rows, you can use `OUTER APPLY` with a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT s.split_value,
       s.position
FROM   table_name t
       OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT LEVEL AS position,
                SUBSTR( t.value, 4 * LEVEL - 3, 4 ) AS split_value
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL( LENGTH( t.value ) / 4 )
       ) s
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'ABCDEFGHIJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456789012' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> SPLIT_VALUE | POSITION
> :---------- | -------:
> ABCD        |        1
> EFGH        |        2
> IJ          |        3
> 1234        |        1
> 5678        |        2
> 9012        |        3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e16e16fa36ce3de495ee2704333751c)*

---

## Update

> if I want to have like 36 <s>words</s> characters in a line how can I modify your 1st answer?

```sql
SELECT s.split_value,
       s.position
FROM   table_name t
       OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT LEVEL AS position,
                 SUBSTR( t.value, 36 * ( LEVEL - 1 ) + 1, 36 ) AS split_value
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL( LENGTH( t.value ) / 36 )
       ) s
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'ABCDEFGHIJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '________10________20________30________40________50________60________70________80' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> SPLIT_VALUE                          | POSITION
> :----------------------------------- | -------:
> ABCDEFGHIJ                           |        1
> ________10________20________30______ |        1
> __40________50________60________70__ |        2
> ______80                             |        3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6fdc9e402ee25039ab13c9be662732cc)*

Comment: Hi Thanks alot if I want to have like 36 words in a line how can I modify your 1st answer?

Comment: @SachiniKarunaratne 36 Words or 36 characters? If it is 36 characters then change every 4 to a 36 and the 3 to a 35. If it is 36 words then it is a very different question and you should probably ask it as a new question.

Comment: 36 or 72 characters :)

Comment: @SachiniKarunaratne Updated